# How to maintain model fields order structure when using south

Tags: python, django, django-south

Suppose I have this model which is associated with south:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now later on I want to add one more field so I created that field between `field_a` and `field_b` now my model looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_c = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then I migrated the changes, when checking the table structure in MySQL the `field_c` is created at the end of all fields. How can I tell south to maintain the fields order e.g. insert after `field_a`.

In MySQL we can insert the new field before or after any existing field. Is it possible to do that in south?

Comment: Why does order matter? Why do you need to update your models so much?

Comment: @frb this is irrelevant reason `Why do you need to update your models so much?` Order matters to me just for a good structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe that it is not possible to force the order of field creation in MySQL when using Django (or South).  New fields will always be appended to the end of the table definition.

However: The order of the columns should be irrelevant to you.  Read on...

If you're writing SQL queries against your database, it is bad form to do `select *` and rely on the field ordering of the table.  Instead you should specify which fields you want to select, and the order in which you want them reported. This makes the underlying tables' field-ordering unimportant.

Additionally, if anyone in your organisation is currently writing reports which use `select *`: by inserting new columns between others you could easily break reports that use field position (rather than field name), as the indexing of the columns will change.

Comment: the need is just to have a good structure. Important fields listed at top and in the same order as they are in model.

Comment: @AamirAdnan If you're writing SQL queries against your database, you shouldn't be doing `select *` - you should specify the order which you  want the fields reported.  This makes field ordering of the underlying tables irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks steve, but it will be good if `south` takes care of it also.

Comment: As we've been saying, it does not and there is no need to. Django South is free software though, so if we're all wrong and it's useful [feel free to add it yourself.](https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src)

Answer (score 1):

As Steve Mayne said, there is no direct way to do it if you keep updating your models. There is a hack to do it though.

The first time you create your model, all definitions go one after another, as you have already observed.

If you want to be absolutely sure of the order of your models after you add a new column, log into the MySQL shell. This is usually done with `mysql -u<user> -p`. Tell it to use your database with `USE db`.

Then, manually insert the new column with `ALTER TABLE table ADD field_c VARCHAR(30) AFTER field_a`.

Now you can tell Django about it by editing your `MyModel` class.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_c = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Obviously, this is really annoying if your model changes a lot. Hopefully that doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I know MySQL does this. The question was does `django-south` supports it or not.

Comment: @AamirAdnan And the answer was no, it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around that has worked for me:

1) Create your model in your model.py file as you would, but add only the first field.

2) Make the migration, but do not migrate yet.

3) Add each field one by one and make migration after each.

4) After having them all, migrate.

This has worked for me. If you have your model designed already, then you can:

0) Delete your model, make migration, migrate, and then undo deleting (you will lose your data, dump it if needed).

1) cut/delete each field from the bottom one by one but the first one.

2) make migration

3) undo to have the 2nd field back and make migration. Repeat for the others.

4) finally, migrate.